# how to give access to a user through ip address stored in database in php without asking for userid and password

Tags: php

I am storing IP addresses of users in my database table at the of registration.
I want to give access to the portal, to some of the registered users without asking for user id and password.
How to give access directly comparing the users IP address to the IP address stored in my database using php.

Comment: Giving access through IP address is not good idea...Because if user is trying to login from different IP will be blocked even though he is real user and will make him frustrating...

Comment: if accessing from different ip address it should ask for user id and password and then it will store the new ip also